# How to capture zero-length ITextSelections using E4 (ACTIVE_SELECTION)?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am trying to port an existing Eclipse plug-in to the E4 programming model, but I am struggling with listing to text selection changes. The old implementation used `ISelectionService#addPostSelectionListener` to register a **post** `ISelectionListener`. This resulted in calls to `selectionChanged` even for zero-length ITextSelections, i.e., for pure cursor movements.

My attempt to use E4’s `@Inject` to achieve the same unfortunately only captures “proper” text selections, i.e., those with positive length:

```
@Inject
@Optional
public void onCursorMovement(
        @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) ITextSelection selection) {
   // selection.getLength() > 0
}
```

How can I opt-in to listening (using `@Inject`) to every cursor movement as was possible using `ISelectionService#addPostSelectionListener`?

(I know that I can achive this using `ESelectionService#addPostSelectionListener` directly, but I would prefer to use the `@Inject` style.)

Comment: Have you tried using the `ESelectionService` directly? What is actually generating the selections?

Comment: You are right: `ESelectionServer#addSelectionListener` behaves consistently with `ACTIVE_SELECTION` **and** also consistently with E3’s `ISelectionService#addSelectionListener`. The mistake I made was that the old code used `ISelectionService#addPostSelectionListener`. The question thus becomes how to get the “active **post** selection” injected in E4 rather than the `ACTIVE_SELECTION`. Any advice, @greg-449?

Comment: I don't think the @Inject supports post selection, you may have to use the  ESelectionService addPostSelectionListener

Comment: I noticed things getting put into the `IEclipseContext` under a key of `org.eclipse.ui.output.postSelection`, but using that together with `@Inject` `@Named` didn’t work for me.